# rollback the data from first table if exception is thrown

Tags: spring, postgresql-9.1, jdbctemplate

I am using spring mvc and postgres as database

I have requirement to insert diff data into two tables with second table has one columns as foreignkey from first table

I am using jdbc template to connect with database

if some exception happens while inserting into second table i want to rollback the data from first table also

for this do i need use spring transactions concept? please suggest

I tried to implement transactions in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


<!-- Define all the service beans that will be created in ePramaan -->
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- END OF DAO beans Definitions -->

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<!-- Create DataSource Bean -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ePramaanDB" />
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcSPProfileRepository" 
   class="in.cdac.epramaan.sp.dao.JdbcSPProfileRepository">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>
```

```
JdbcSPProfileRepository is a class it contains method to insert data to database
I annotated class with @Transactional
But when i run the server it is throwing exceptions
```

14:44:01.223 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcSPProfileRepository': Injection of autowired depende
ncies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: in.cdac.epramaan.common.bd.
MasterConfigBD in.cdac.epramaan.sp.dao.JdbcSPProfileRepository.masterConfigBD; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanD
efinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [in.cdac.epramaan.common.bd.MasterConfigBD] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which
qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=t
rue)}

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class JdbcSPProfileRepository implements SPProfileRepository {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(JdbcSPProfileRepository.class);
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

/** The master config bd. */
@Autowired
MasterConfigBD masterConfigBD;

@Autowired
public JdbcSPProfileRepository(DataSource dataSource) {

}

@Override
@Transactional
public SPRegistrationResponse saveSPRegistrationDetails(
        final SPRegistration spreg) {
    SPRegistrationResponse spRegResponse = new SPRegistrationResponse();
    Response response = null;
    logger.debug("In saveSPRegistrationDetails : ");
    try {/////}catch(){}
    }
   }
```

```
can anybody please suggest the solution
```

Comment: Try to implement it with what you have in your mind and if somethings come up we will be happy to help.

Comment: Hey JavaBond I tried with above but getting exception on server

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. One as you suggest is use Spring transactions. 
http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html
Or you can implemente your own ACID method where sharing the connection between transactions make it atomic. Look this example.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/commit-rollback.htm

The key is only commit on you connection("con") when you want finish your transaction. Then if something goes wrong before finish all your micro transactions, since you did not commit yet nothing will be persisted on your database.